# Godot 3.4: Quest System Task Advancement

Tags: arrays, dictionary, 2d, godot

So I managed to solve my previous problem about not being able to modify a dictionary(stupid me), but now im more or less stuck on the concept of task advancement.

So I have a quest system(dictionary), with sub-dictionaries such as "tasks"
I want a single function to advance the quest, and I'm thinking something like this:

```
if not all_tasks in Quest are complete:
   find the first task that has a "completed" bool value of false
   change bool value to true
else: (all tasks have "completed" value of true)
   complete quest instead.
```

And I'm thinking it will have to be an array of tasks.
But I'm not sure how to implement this and I keep getting stuck on the logic. It's way easier to write it out logically than to actually implement it in code.

So, what do you think? Is this a valid way of going about this? is there a better way?
If this is a good way, how would I go about finding the first task in the array that is not complete, and then complete it?

Comment: "Its way easier to write it out logically than to actually implement it in code." Take every step of what you write, and break it down into smaller steps. Eventually the steps will be small and clear enough that you can write the code for them. A couple suggestions that will make the transition to code easier: 1. Try to not be ambiguous with your steps. For example "change bool value to true", which bool value? it does not say. In this case you need a variable. 2. You may need to consider exceptional paths. For example, what if you don't find a task? This would lead to reorganize the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
func advanceQuest(questName: String):
if PlayerData.playerData.quests_active.has(questName):
    
    var taskList = []
    
    if PlayerData.playerData.quests_active.get(questName).get("taskType") == 0:
        for task in PlayerData.playerData.quests_active.get(questName).get("tasks"):
            if PlayerData.playerData.quests_active.get(questName).get("tasks").get(task).get("completed") == false:
                taskList.append(task)
        if taskList != []:
            PlayerData.playerData.quests_active[questName]["tasks"][taskList[0]]["completed"] = true
        else:
            completeQuest(questName)
            
    else:
        #Syncronous Task Type
        pass
else:
```

Got it!!!!!

Comment: You only need the first element you add to `taskList`. You could have a variable for a single task, and when you find a task in the loop set the variable and break from the loop (with `break`). Then, after the loop, either you set the the variable and broke from the loop, or you completed the loop without setting the variable. So you check if the variable was set (that could be checking against null, or if null is not an option, you could have an auxiliary variable set to true if you found the task).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).